# update record by adding a value to existing value sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using REPLACE statement to insert/update records in a table with composite primary key.
How can I add a new value to existing value and update the record using REPLACE statement?
Here's my sql:

```
function leaveBalanceRecord($f3)
{
    $userID = $this->f3->get('userID');
    $leaveType = $this->f3->get('leaveType');
    $leaveBalance = $this->f3->get('leaveBalance');
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO users_leave_balance 
    (user_id, period, leave_type, leave_balance, rollable_till_date)
    VALUES ($userID, '2017-01-03', $leaveType, $leaveBalance, 3.05)";
    $results = $this->db->exec($sql);
    return $results;
}
```

Eg. I have a following record:

```
user_id  |  period  |  leave_type  |  leave_balance
134      |  2017-01 |  1           |  10.0
```

Now if user tries to insert another record with user_id - 134, period - 2017-01, leave_type - 1, and leave_balance - 3, I need to add the current balance 3 to existing balance 10.0 and update 13.0

`user_id, period, and leave_type` columns constitute a **Composite key**

Comment: Can you please provide more detailed and clear question ? "How can I add a new value to existing value and update the record using REPLACE statement? " this one is not clear

Comment: @KhayyamSadigov Sorry for that obscurity. I have edited the post.

Comment: Now is clear. Thanks.

Firstly select if there is a row with same user_id, period, and leave_type. And if there is then UPDATE it. If there is not then INSERT new row

Comment: I suspect that you're really after INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: @Strawberry I have multi-column primary key .. so INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE doesn't work as desired..

Comment: Whether the PK is multi-column or not makes no difference.

Comment: As DOC states "... If a=1 OR b=2 matches several rows, only one row is updated. In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause on tables with multiple unique indexes"... please correct me if I am misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work with `REPLACE INTO`, but you can use a combination of `INSERT INTO`, `ON DUPLICATE KEY` and `UPDATE` while `UPDATE` will provide a way to concat new with existing data.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO users SET userid = 8, username = "Foobar"
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE username = CONCAT(username, "123")
```

This will basically try to insert a new user with the userid "8" and the username "Foobar". The userid is my primary key. If it exists, it will instead update the existing user and append "123" to its username.

Comment: but I guess it doesn't work as expected in case of multi-column primary key.. or does it?